# Swift: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS even with guard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I don't understand why my app crashes here randomly.

```
if PlayerViewController.canUpdate {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {


                guard !(self.barView?.isHidden ?? false) else { . //crash_happens_here
                     return;
                }

                do {
                    self.barView?.updateBuffer(pcmBuffer.mBuffers.mData?.assumingMemoryBound(to: CFloat.self), withBufferSize: UInt32(numberFramesOut / 2));

                }
            }
        }
```

The complete code is here.

Comment: What's the error message exactly and where exactly does it happen in your code?

Comment: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x119ef918).
debugger stops at guard

Comment: And is there a message in console?

Comment: No there is no message in console. It just crashes at the guard statement. and shows the following statement in the editor 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x119ef918)'.

Comment: The crash is probably purely diagnostic. The problem has already happened elsewhere. Turn on Zombies and try to elicit the issue.

Comment: If `barView` is an outlet, make sure it is well connected

Comment: As I said it crashes randomly. If it was a problem with the connection it must have crashed every time I run this code. It happens sometimes When I either present or dismiss the view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `self.barView` is both Optional and `weak`. Try making this a normal strong reference. That is sometimes enough to make this sort of error go away.

Comment: that's a better guess

Comment: @DeveloperSheldon ok but leave your answer up, I retracted my comment

Comment: I double checked it and I think mine is wrong because his code is not crashing inside of the scope, instead it is crashing at the line of guarding, so my answer didn't make sense and I don't want to mislead other guys.

Comment: This answer seems reasonable. And I didn't see the crash for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Probably 'Self' or 'barView' doesn't exist when the guard is executed, try using 
StrongSelf and adding the barView to the guard

```
if let strongSelf = self, let barView = strongSelf.barView {
    guard !(barView.isHidden ?? false) else { . ....
}
```